# Xamarin button text change in code behind

Tags: xamarin

Here my code sample

```
  <controls:SwitchboardButton Grid.Row="0"   Grid.Column="0" Label="Test">
    <controls:SwitchboardButton.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer   Tapped="CameraButtonTapped" />
    </controls:SwitchboardButton.GestureRecognizers>
  </controls:SwitchboardButton>
```

This is code behind

```
    public async void CameraButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TensePage());
    }
```

i want to know how to change button text when click button. i want to do this Code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a name to your button

```
<controls:SwitchboardButton x:Name="btnSwitch" Grid.Row="0"   Grid.Column="0" Label="Test">
```

then in the code behind:

```
public async void CameraButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    btnSwitch.Text = "Some New Text";

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TensePage());
}
```